# Is there a way to give up ownership of the death note without losing the shingami eyes?

Tags: death-note

Let's say, John owns two death notes. One belongs to Ryuk and the other belongs to for Example Ragnarok. He makes the eyedeal with Ryuk, then, he gives ownership from the death note Ragnarok brought him. Will he now lose the shingiami eyes?

Comment: probably not as in this situation he is still a death note owner. I think you lose the eyes under the same conditions you would lose your memory.

Comment: @DarkYagami sorry i misread so i've deleted by answer for now, i can't find any evidence as i don't think it's ever stated what happens when a human has 2 Shinigami following them. i have a theory about the Eye Deal actually being made with the Shinigami who owns the Death Note and by giving up that Death Note you will loose the eyes (even if you own the other from another Shinigami). however this is flawed as it doesn't account for what happens with a Death Note without a Shinigami Owner like Rem's in the anime

Answer (score 1):

On chapter 5, Ryuk stated that the shinigami eye was a deal between the shinigami and the human owner of a certain note, so it will probably be associated to that relationship, so the eye will be gone as soon as the shinigami leaves his side.